# Первые два символа в слове

Tags: регулярные-выражения, phpstorm

Нужно регулярное выражение для Phpstorm.
Нужно найти все слова в которых первые два символа - bi.
Например в слове biMas первые два символа - bi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот регулярное выражение для Phpstorm или Webstorm (для поиска-замены в интерфейсе IDE) для нахождения целых слов, начинающихся с bi:

`\bbi\w*`

Для замены "bi" на другую подстроку, например на "AAA", нужно в поиске взять остаток слова в группу: `\bbi(\w*)` и в строке замены вернуть значение группы после заменённой подстроки: `AAA$1`

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, `(?<=^|[^\w])` можно заменить на `\b`.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty Спасибо, поправил ответ

Comment: А не подскажите для замены этих двух символов какую регулярку можно использовать?

Comment: @Berkins дополнил ответ

Comment: Круто все работает. Спасибо большое